# Snippet lookahead trigger

Tags: regular-expression, plugin-ultisnips

Using UltiSnips, I'm wondering if it's possible to do some lookahead assertion when detecting the trigger.

For example, this works:

```
snippet "dv" "derivative" ir
\dv{$1}{$2}$0
endsnippet
```

But this doesn't even get triggered:

```
snippet "dv(?=[ \n])" "derivative" ir
\dv{$1}{$2}$0
endsnippet
```

I've had similar issue with negative lookahead, except it always gets triggered regardless. I'd like to know if there is some possible workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Lookaheads are currently not supported by UltiSnips<sup>*</sup>, these include both positive and negative lookahead assertions.

You could use a **context** (see `:h UltiSnips-custom-context-snippets`) to
inspect the text after the cursor. The cursor position is accessible with `snip.cursor`:

```
global !p

def text_after_cursor_matches(snip, string):
    (line, col) = snip.cursor
    text_after_cursor = snip.buffer[line][col:]
    # print(text_after_cursor)
    return re.match(string, text_after_cursor)

endglobal

context text_after_cursor_matches(snip, "[ \n]")
snippet dv "derivative" i
\dv{$1}{$2}
endsnippet
```

Above I used a custom function `text_after_cursor_matches()` to check if the characters that follow after the cursor matches a certain regex (`"[ \n]"` in this case). If True, the snippet is expanded.

<sup>*: as implied from the maintainer's response to [this issue](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/1481)</sup>